# Django MySQL Query Json field

Tags: mysql, django

I have a MySQL database with a table containing a JSON field called things.  The JSON looks like this

> things = {"value1": "phil", "value2": "jill"}

I have collection of objects that I have pulled from the database via

```
my_things = Name_table.objects.values
```

Now, I'd like to filter the my_things collection by one of the JSON fields.  I've tried this

> my_things =
>   my_things.filter(things__contains={'value': 'phil'})

which returned an empty collection.  I've also tried

> my_things = my_things.filter(things={'value': 'phil'})

and

> my_things = my_things.filter(things__exact={'value': 'phil'})

I'n using Django 1.10 and MySQL 5.7
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how exactly do you store JSON in field. If you use [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield), then your `things` will be string without spaces, with strings inside of quotation marks: `'{"value1":"phil","value2":"jill"}'`.

Then, via [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#contains):

```
my_things = my_things.filter(things__contains='"value1":"phil"')
```

should return your filtered QuerySet, because

```
>>> tmp_str = '{"value1":"phil","value2":"jill"}'
>>> '"value1":"phil"' in tmp_str
True
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it returns an empty collection still.  The data was not stored using djang-jsonfield, it was stored from a non web python application just using python's builtin json library.

Comment: The really odd thing is my_things contains several items before I apply the filter and 0 items afterwards.

Comment: Ignore my previous comments  - your suggestion worked.